Is it possible to use `nix` instead of `apt` as package manager on Ubuntu?
I am really interested in using nix to manage my packages on Ubuntu. Is it possible? If so, what are the caveats/contraindications in doing that?

Possible - yes. Caveats - you will most likely end up breaking your system

I'm not sure anyone has ever tried this and returned to tell the tale. Curious how far you get before it all goes to splat.

Is it even Ubuntu anymore if you let a different package manager install stuff that doesn't include the changes made by Ubuntu to upstream packages? What is the definition of "distribution", is a "distribution" mostly defined by the package manager that it uses? Are we alone in the universe? And all that jazz

@kos As insightful as a potato.

As insightful as whoever's reading it is capable of making it. The "insightful" associated risks to such manouvre have been pointed out to you already, so what's left to do is to think about whether it'd even make sense (which since you prefer bluntness, IMO should've been the first thought) - which I tried and put in a humorous way. But I can put it more bluntly and say the same thing explicitly: why would you transform Ubuntu into something else instead of installing something else (such as NixOS) directly, when the endevaour and associated risks with such task are definetly not worth it?
